# google-chrome не показывает текст

Tags: google-chrome

После обновления, google-chrome перестал показывать текстовое содержание всех сайтов. Т.е. структура их видна, картинки видны, а текста нет...

Порылся в иНете, говорят, что это проблема с загрузкой шрифтов. Но я ничего не могу сделать, так как в самом хроме окно "Настройки" тоже пустое - текста там нет. Хотя какие-то кнопочки и выпадающие списки видны (без текста).

Единственное, что сделал - переустановил. Эффекта не дало.

ОС : Fedora 38. google-chrome-stable Версия : 113.0.5672.63

Есть какие-то рекомендации ?

Comment: Любопытно, что если в python программе запустить chrome-driver и использовать его в Selenium,  то всё нормально смотрится...

Comment: И ещё одна мысль... В конце прошлого года читал, что правообладатели многих популярных компьютерных шрифтов отозвали свои лицензии в России... Может с этим как-то связано?  Как сменить шрифты в хроме, не запуская сам хром ?

Answer (score 0):

Сегодня ОС выполнила автоматическое обновление google-chrome  до версии 113.0.5672.92. Проблемы больше нет.